# npm install often pending after download

Tags: node.js

when i run npm install  ,
it often pending after download someting,
i wait so much time,but still  cannot download .

like this

```
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite/-/iconv-lite-0.2.11.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.1.22.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/exit/-/exit-0.1.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/getobject/-/getobject-0.1.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml/-/js-yaml-2.0.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-0.9.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/dateformat/-/dateformat-1.0.2-1.2.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/eventemitter2/-/eventemitter2-0.4.13.tgz

npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
```

then nothing happend,what would i do? reinstall it,or is there a solution to solve the npm install?

Comment: Remove the `node_modules` directory and start again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
npm cache clean
```

and then

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

and run

```
npm install
```